# Crytpographic theory books?

Tags: game-theory, cryptography

I was reading a paper in communication mechanisms, [and the tools that are used from the authors](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.3982/TE944)
have been taken from cryptograpgy. If anyone have some time to check the paper nd see the proof of theorem $1$ in $6.1$ section, you can see from your own that they use cryptographic theory. Does anybody know any cryptography book where I could become more familiar with the notions of permutation, encryption and decryption from the mathematical point of view?

Comment: This (IMO trivial) paper does not use any "cryptography" at all. Go do something useful...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what do you mean by IMO trivial? and do you know cryptography?

Comment: yes, it’s my job. The paper is quite bad IMO. I assume you’ve tried to read it?

Comment: Yes I tried at some point but it is not easy...most papers of the specific subject...but as you can see the journal is one of the top ones...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what is this ``secret sharing" idea that they presnet in section $5$? Could you please give the intuition, I understand that it has to do with the fact of sharing information, but  since you are an expert in cryptography could you please explain some things? :)

Comment: Look for secret sharing Shamir online. That’s the most common scheme. Every participant has a share of the secret that by itself reveals nothing about it. But if enough ( what enough means depends on the schema used, say a majority or all of them) put their shares together they can reconstruct the secret. Else they know nothing. Most often achieved by some linear algebra tricks over finite fields.

Comment: I think I can start with this https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/359168.359176 and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing

Comment: @HennoBrandsma last question! Assuming that we have a game with $\kappa$ agents and we want to construct such a mechanism of communication, the assumtion here is that the players communicate each other  only in pairs or we assume this for simplicity? For example we have 10 players. If we assume that $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}$, $\{5,6\}$, $\{7,8\}$,$\{9,10\}$ form such pairs, the players can communicate differently as well, namely in the following pairs $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,4\}$, $\{5,7\}$, $\{6,9\}$,$\{8,10\}$ as well. How can we write donw these combinations?